# Were started overboard into... What does it mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, infinitives

I came across this piece while reading *[The Ghost of Art](http://www.online-literature.com/dickens/reprinted-pieces/9/)* by Charles Dickens:

> It appears to me as if there were too much talk and too much law - as
> if some grains of truth **were started overboard into** a tempestuous sea
> of chaff.

I don't understand the grammar. Shouldn't it be "were started **to** overboard into..." or "were starting overboarding into"?

Comment: **overboard** is an adverb, so there is no **to overboard** and no **overboarding**. The bit that doesn't seem to make sense is **started**... if it were replaced by **thrown** then it would make a coherent sentence.

Comment: Start as a verb meaning 'throw' or 'propel' was more common in Dickens' time than now. When people are surprised we can still say their eyes start out of their head.

Answer (score 2):

In Patrick O'Brian's novels of the British Navy in the Napoleonic Wars, he quite often uses the expression *start our/their water* to indicate that a ship which is being pursued, or which has run aground, pumps out most of its supplies of drinking water to reduce its weight. The only likely definition of *start* I can find online is this from Oxford : *be displaced or displace by pressure or shrinkage.*

I take it that this is the sense in which Dickens uses it, of a valued commodity being jettisoned from a ship.

Answer (score 0):

As JavaLatte says in a comment, "overboard" is an adverb, not a verb. It is almost always used in the phrases "thrown overboard" or "fell overboard", meaning to be thrown off a ship into the water or to fall off a ship. It is common to use it in the phrase "went overboard" to mean that something was carried to an extreme. Like, "Mary likes to make sure she brings enough clothes for a trip, but she really went overboard when she brought four suitcases for an overnight stay."

In this case, the writer says that there was "too much talk" and "too much law". So he basically wants to say that they "went overboard" on talk and law. But he apparently doesn't want to state it quite that strongly, so instead of saying they actually "went overboard" he softens it to they "started overboard". They're not actually overboard yet, but they're started in that direction.

"... into a sea of ..." If you are thrown overboard, you presumably fall into the sea. So to say "... overboard into a sea ..." is just making the metaphor more specific. In this case, he wants to say "a sea of chaff". Obviously in this case it's not a literal sea of water.

Comment: Just a minor correction: overboard is an adverb, not an adjective. Thank you!

Comment: @Rusletov Duh, yes. Brain freeze. I'll fix that.